# appharbor [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified] with model first EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I have a small project where I used continuous integration with bitbucket and appharbor When I published the project the login is working normally and so on but other database connections gives the following error:

> The system cannot find the file specified
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

here are my local connection strings

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ZeinyCenter-20130614160141;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="Model1Container" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=aspnet-ZeinyCenter-20130614160141;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and here is the appharbor connection string

```
Server=576666e4-329e-4511-95b9-a1dd00ff4766.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;Database=db576666e4329e451195b9a1dd00ff4766;User ID=yusmzpttdopksbua;Password=H3Ex6jp3wihobPu3W2KZHBpW7tDk8SWtxYWTxabXGXhVBGTAnRJZz6AgLRzKNe4L;
```

Can someone please help me

Comment: Could you post the full stack-trace?

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem typing the `connectionString` that appharbor gave me on the `Web.config`.

Steps:

1) Go to appharbor and select your application.

2) Click on add-on, and select SQL Server (install the free one).

3) Then click on Go to SQL Server.

4) Scroll to the bottom  and you will see Connection string.

5) Copy all (Click it and press ctrl+A), the part that says `Server=bla bla bla`.

6) Now go to Visual Studio --> Web.config and paste it in:

```
add name="DefaultConnection" 
connectionString="Your appharbor connectionString" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Example, mine was like this:

```
add name="DefaultConnection" 
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
    Initial Catalog=aspnet-DeliveriandoWebApp-20131019135542;
    Integrated Security=SSPI;
    AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-DeliveriandoWebApp-20131019135542.mdf"     
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now is like this:

```
add name="DefaultConnection" 
connectionString="Server=8a6b279b-0441-49c7-a97e-a2860049ea89.sqlserver.sequelizer.com;
    Database=db8edfdf6c279c044149e7a17ea2860049ea89;
    User ID=lolyctkwkaebnkj3;
    Password=nYhP4hZKDNMLftEaSyeeeS8eVpbs3H3seUZQUQ8PZzMRXA5hPVfDirfPwZzHfvaFDsz;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```